# Reading resource file uber jar build with maven-shade-plugin

Tags: java, maven, jar, executable-jar, maven-shade-plugin

I have a simple project that reads the resource `.yaml` file:

```
var yamlObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
var classLoader = Application.class.getClassLoader();
var file = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(classLoader.getResource("config.yaml")).getFile());
var appConfig = yamlObjectMapper.readValue(file, ApplicationConfig.class);
```

So it works fine from the IDE. Now I want to build an executable uber JAR that will include all the resources inside. I'm using `maven-shade-plugin`.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>mypackage.Application</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So I'm expecting the resources files to be included in the jar. And when I'm executing `jar tf myapplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` I can see that inside the jar there is file `config.yaml`. However when I try to run it with `java -jar` I receive the `java.io.FileNotFoundException` with message that `config.yaml` cannot be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution provided to me by **Andrea Boccacci**. Here is his answer that he alow me to post here:

Your file is inside a jar file so you can't access it from `File` class try to use `getResourceAsStream` and then swap to `readValue(InputStream, Class)` if there's such an API.
if not you can write the input stream to an actual temp file then call `readValue(File, Class)` and then delete the extracted file.

So here is how my code looks right now and it works:

```
var yamlObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
var classLoader = Application.class.getClassLoader();
var resource = classLoader.getResourceAsStrean("config.yaml");
var appConfig = yamlObjectMapper.readValue(resource, ApplicationConfig.class);
```